# Invert boolean and convert to string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, type-conversion, boolean

How to invert boolean and after that convert it to string? Following code returns boolean value `false` instead of desirebale string `"true"` :

```
let bool = false;
console.log(!bool.toString()); // false
```

Comment: `(!bool).toString()`

Answer (score 1):

Order of operations. Need to use parenthesis.

```js
let bool = false;
console.log((!bool).toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

2 ways

```js
let bool = false;
console.log(String(!bool)); // false
```

```js
let bool = false;
console.log((!bool).toString());
```